# How can you use a address from ipv6 subnet?

Tags: networking, ipv6

I have a VPS running Debian 10 and I have for example the following /64 subnet:
`2001:db8:abcd:abcd::/64`
How can I use a single IP from this subnet?
For example if I want to use this single IPv6 for a process: `2001:db8:abcd:abcd::1234/128`, what do I have to add to /etc/network/interfaces to make it work? By default it doesn't respond to pings and it just timeouts.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try  `ip address add  2001:db8:abcd:abcd::1234 dev enp1s0`. (The device should be changed depending of your configuration).

If this works, add the following lines in the `/etc/network/interfaces` to make the new address added in the boot process.

```
iface enp1s0 inet6 static
        address 2001:db8:abcd:abcd::1234
```

Note, that, when you said you have a `2001:db8:abcd:abcd::/64` network, you are only sure to be able to use the ::0 address, the whole `2001:db8:abcd:abcd::/64` doesn’t necessarily belongs to you (one of the address is your gateway and is attached to the VPS (virtual) router). But I think however you should be able to use all the 2^64-1 addresses remaining. (I have tried with a ::1 address, it works !)

Comment: You need a subnet mask in there somewhere

Comment: The default netmask is 128 which is ok for an secondary address. I assume that a primary address is already set with a 64 bits netmask… and it won’t be deleted.